# Rewrite date from the Twitter Search API

Tags: php, twitter, date-format

I'm currently creating a PHP function retrieving Twitter feed according to a certain search.

I had no difficulty with json to get all I want and convert it to PHP.

I have only one problem, which is the date format. When i get it, it sorts like this :

```
Sat, 09 Feb 2013 14:08:27 +0000
```

Does someone have an idea oh how could I transform it to be like this : 9 Feb 2013, 14:08

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feed the date into either `strtotime` which will give you something you then can use with the `date` method.

```
$formattedDate = date('d M Y, H:i', strtotime(yourdate));
```

Or, alternatively, go the OOP way and use the `DateTime` object and then using `DateTime::format`

```
$dt = new DateTime(yourdate);
$formattedDate = $dt->format('d M Y, H:i');
```